# bash truncate last n chars of a string

Tags: string, bash, truncation

How can I truncate the last n chars from a string in bash ?

In python I would use

```
new_string = var_name[:-n]
```

Is there a simple solution like this in bash ?

Comment: [check](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144298/delete-the-last-character-of-a-string-using-string-manipulation-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in BASH string functions:

```
s='123456'
echo "${s:0: -2}"
1234

echo "${s:0: -3}"
123
```

Comment: Nice! Note that `${s::-3}` is equivalent. That is, `0` is the default value of the 2nd block.

Comment: both ${s::-2} and ${s:0: -2} work on the command line but when i put them in a bash script it returns an error " bash_test.sh: line 5:  -2: substring expression < 0"

Comment: Are you sure you have `#!/bin/bash` as first line or executing that script under bash using `bash ./script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Use sed,

```
var=$(sed 's/.{n}$//' <<< "$str")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sed like this:

```
$ var=lknjn
$ newvar=$(echo $var |sed 's/n$//g')
$ echo $newvar
lknj
```